# Compute multiple integral of function $\frac{xy}{2}$ within a domain D that is area formed by following curves: $L_1: x=0, L_2: x^2+y^2=4, L_3:y=-x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So I need to do a multiple integral and first I wanted to know does it matter which way I do it, first integrate by $y$ and then  by $x$ or vice verse. I gather that it would be any different, because the integrals $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are equal. I first wanted to integrate it by $y$, because it's simpler that way.

$$\int^{\sqrt{2}}_0 \int^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-x} \frac{xy}{2}dydx+\int^2_{\sqrt{2}} \int^{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\frac{xy}{2}dydx=\int^{\sqrt{2}}_0 \left. \frac{xy^2}{4}\right|^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-x}dx + 0=\frac{4x-x^3}{4}-\frac{x^3}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\int^{\sqrt{2}}_0 4x-2x^3 dx=\left. \frac{x^2}{2}\right|^{\sqrt{2}}_0=\frac{1}{4} (2x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}\left. \right|^{\sqrt{2}}_0)=\frac{7}{8}$$

I assume that this answer is incorrect as it would be too simple. So, I would like to know here my error is. Also, I don't know if I get noting right, because it looks like too integral multiplication in the beginning, but I heard that it doesn't matter where do you write that $dx$, I may be awfully wrong. The second question is about the domain that I try to calculate. I sketched the domain and from there it looks like the function $x^2+y^2=4$ is above the $y=-x$ so I made the $-x$ the lower bound of the integral and $2-x$ the upper. The same goes, where I calculate the other integral by $y$.

Comment: It is not clear what the domain $D$ consists of. Which portions of the three curves bound $D$?

Comment: Well the domain is the area that is made by those curves $L_1,L_2 \text{ and } L_3$

Comment: The curves bound four mutually exclusive regions.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I should compute the area which is bounded by all of these curves. I sketched and it is a section of a circle. First quadrant + a little bit of second quadrant. With radius 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "below $x=0$"? $x=0$ is the $y$-axis.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales True, now I am confused.

Comment: You have two lines and a circle centered at their intersection. Look at the drawing provided in the submitted answer, but disregard the horizontal line, since it is not one of the boundaries. Then you have four possible domains. But because of the symmetry of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{2}$, there will be only two possible results for the integral (if unions of the four regions are not considered). In any event, you should use polar integration as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Ok, so could be then, that the task has two answers and I should simply calculate for two possible areas? Also, in my exercise it is noted that I should calculate the integral in Descartes coordinates.

Comment: Yes, calculate both areas to be safe, noting that the domain asked for in the exercise is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Ok, so then the question remains, does it matter whether I first integrate the $dy$ or $dx$ integral?

Comment: It does not matter. The complexity of the calculation will be the same either way.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales So, is my result correct as of now? When calculating the area in Descartes' coordinates, I am not sure how to differentiate between that small section of circle and that bigger one in respect to lower and upper bound. Now I have done supposedly the bigger section of the circle not that small one, but am not sure as to how would they differ. The only thing maybe, is that for the smaller area the lower bound will be the function $x=2-y$ and upper bound will be $x=0$? Either way I'm confused.

Comment: I have set it up for the larger of the two possible domains and posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP specifies in the comments that the integral must be done using Cartesian coordinates, here is an indication of how to set that up for one of the possible domains.

The "blue" domain is fairly straightforward but the "orange" domain must be broken into two parts depending upon whether $0\le x\le\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{2}\le x\le2$
when integrating in the order $dx\,dy$. If integrating in the order $dy\,dx$ the integral will have to be broken into two parts depending upon whether $-\sqrt{2}\le y\le0$ or $0\le y\le2$.

[image: Graph of domains]

$$ \int_D\int\frac{xy}{2}\,dA=\int_0^\sqrt{2}\int_{-x}^\sqrt{4-x^2}\frac{xy}{2}\,dy\,dx +\int_\sqrt{2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^\sqrt{4-x^2}\frac{xy}{2}\,dy\,dx$$

You should find that the first integral has a value of $\frac{1}{2}$ and the second, a value of $0$.

Comment: Ok, I have numerous questions. 1) Why do you divide area in two, and why at $x=sqrt{2}$ it's not defied? 2) I don't understand the y integral bounds. First What does $-sqrt{4-x^2}$ represent?

Comment: I think you are going to need a one-on-one session with a tutor and review graphing of functions. The stack exchange format is not suitable for tutoring. Ask yourself what are the coordinates of the point in quadrant 4 where the line $y=-x$ intersects the circle $x^2+y^2=4$. Then notice that the part of the orange region to the left of the dotted line has a different lower boundary than the part to the right of the dotted line. So you will need two integrals, one for each of the two lower bounds.

Comment: What I find weird is that the value of the integral is one half. Doesn't this integral represent a area of the circle? It looks like the section of the circle I am integrating is less than a half of circle. More like $\frac{3\pi}{8}$

Comment: No, the integral is not the area of a circle, because you are finding the signed volume of a solid, not the area of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The domain is a portion of the circle centered at the origin with radius equal to $2$ and therefore the set up should be in polar coordinates

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_0^2\frac{\cos \theta \sin \theta}{2} r^3drd\theta=$$

where the limit for $\theta$ depends upon which part we are considering for the domain.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I need first to do Descartes coordinates and then polar. And your explanation is so not understandable.

Comment: @user As already noticed, you should clarify which part of the domain you are considering.

Comment: @user In this case by polar coordinates we just need to that $\theta_1=-\pi/4$ and $\theta_2=3\pi/4$. In cartesian we need to divide in 2 parts.

Comment: Did you mean $r^3dr\,d\theta$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes of course! Thanks I fix that

Comment: @user When I try to calculate the smaller area I get the result of $-0.5$ Because the integrating bounds are $\frac{3\pi}{4} \text{ and } \frac{\pi}{2}$ respectively. And it computes as $\frac{1}{2}-1=-\frac{1}{2}$. Can you help me?

Comment: Notice that the function is symmetric with respect to the origin. $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$ and is positive in quadrants I, III and negative in quadrants II, IV. So the result between $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ should be negative and is, indeed, equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$. The larger region should therefore have a result of $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$. Do you see why?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I am not totally sure that I see right, but maybe because the are consists of one section in II quadrant which is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and then two sections equal to the one in II quadrant, only they are located in a III quadrant, so the sign is positive. Am I correct?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales And for some reason when I try to integrate it using Cartesian coordinates I get a wrong result. See my edit to the post.