# Calculating area defined by curves $L_1: y=-x \text{, } L_2:y^2+x^2=4 \text{ and } L_3:x=0$ using multible integrals and Polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I need to find an area that is formed by three curves: $L_1: y=-x \text{, } L_2:y^2+x^2=4 \text{ and } L_3:x=0$. I understand that these curves make two different areas, so I am trying to compute both of them.

So, as I understand the integrals that need to be computed is $$\int^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}\int^2_0r^3sin\theta cos\theta drd\theta=4\int^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}_{\frac{-\pi}{4}} sin\theta cos\theta d\theta =2(sin^2(\theta)\left.\right|^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}) =2(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{{2}})=2\sqrt{2}$$

Is it correct or have I made a mistake?

The second area:

$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int^2_0 r^3sin\theta cos\theta = 2(sin^2(\theta)\left.\right|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{3\pi}{4}})=2(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=2-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: You posted an [almost identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464813/compute-multiple-integral-of-function-fracxy2-within-a-domain-d-that-is-a) days ago and accepted an answer. People complained *there* that there are a number of possible regions. Why don't you get the problem phrased correctly or ask your teacher to fix it?

Comment: @TedShifrin I myself don't know which of the two areas should I compute, so I do both of them.I accepted an answer where the area was computed using Cartesian coordinates, for me these are two different exercises.

Comment: @EricTowers I think there are only two distinct areas. I compute for both of them and on the post I give the bounds of each integral.

Comment: No, there are indeed 4 possible regions, as was explained to you before. Your second integral corresponds to one of them. Your first does not. And the region could be underneath $y=-x$, so there are two options there.

Comment: @TedShifrin Are you here for a conflict by any means? Yes, there are four regions but two distinct areas ( like the regions are symmetrical to one another, so it doesn't matter whether I choose to integrate with bounds from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ or from $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The same goes with the smaller two areas.

Comment: The area form in polar coordinates is $r \,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\theta$.  Why are you using $r^3 \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\theta$?

Comment: @EricTowers As far as I know $x=rsin(\theta) \text{ and } y=rcos(\theta)$

Comment: @user : Those are the transformed coordinates, not areas.

Answer (score 1):

There are four finite regions.
[image: Plot of the bounding curves]

The region with (polar) angles between $-\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$ has area
$$  \int_0^2 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/2} r \,\mathrm{d}\theta \,\mathrm{d}r  = \int_0^2 \frac{3\pi}{4} r \,\mathrm{d}r = \left. \frac{3\pi}{4} \frac{r^2}{2} \right|^2_0 = \frac{3\pi}{2}  \text{.}  $$

The areas of the other three regions are entirely analogous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the region is defined as:

[image]

Why work so hard with integrals?  The area is the sum of a quarter of a circular disk of radius $2$ and a right triangle with sides equal $2$:

$$A = \frac{1}{4} \pi 2^2 + \frac{1}{2} 2 \cdot 2$$

The first portion is trivial in polar coordinates:

$$A_1 =\int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/4} 2 \theta d\theta$$

The second is only slightly more tricky:

$$\int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{-\pi/4} \frac{2 \theta}{\cos \theta}\ d\theta$$

Comment: Because I have an assignment where I have to calculate the area using multiple integrals. :)